# Organization db for blog posts with Mysql and Php

Tags: php, mysql

I intend to write a blog for life stories. I will post my photos and text and share it with other people. At the very beginning there was a question, how to organize a database?
I'm going to do so in the article would be a photo and text.
While there is an option in my head - for each article - to make a new table, but I don’t know, are they doing this?
But here I also have a question. Photos for one day can be 30 pieces, and maybe 0. There is an option to attach photos to the text, or vice versa, but I do not know how to be more literate. By this, I can not start work.
I have to say that this is my first site, I will use mySQL + PHP.

My try is this

```
id int(11)
user_id int(11)
datecreated timestamp 
dateupdated timestamp
content text
title varchar(255)
h1 varchar(255)
```

But what about the images?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You first should decide, how you want to present the photos - Embedded in the article or as gallery after it - or both - or what ever.

Comment: photos in the blog in different places!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you would probaly rename the photos to a random filename and store them in a folder somewhere. And then store the file location in the DB.

But why not use something like wordpress?
If you want a custom gui with wordpress use the rest api or make a theme. No need to reinvent the wheel.